# Is there a timeout on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, connectivity

When I log in to a Stack Exchange site such as *[Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Music: Practice & Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour)* and *[Super User](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#Super_User)*, I notice after around half an hour being on the site my connection seems to drop, loading questions and pages stops dead... Is there a session timer on Stack Exchange sites that I need to be aware of?

I just have to run another Internet Explorer session to get the Stack Exchange sites to load again...

Comment: I run the sites much longer in IE without the issue you describe. Are you using a proxy? Are you on a corperate network with specific connection rules?

Comment: I realise that I am at work so it maybe due to our proxy settings...